# Assign aksapp.io to valid DNS name

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created a web service in azure kubernetes through Visual studio and when i opened my site from the below url its working.

URL is : http://myapp.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.aksapp.io/

Now i want to assign a valid DNS name i.e. abc.com to open my web service/Website.

So is it possible that i can open my service through valid DNS name or is their any other solution to open above link from valid DNS name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this annotations in your service template:

`service:
    annotations: service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name: "mycustomdnsname"`

This [blog](https://github.com/dtzar/blog/tree/master/K8sIngressDNS) explains in more details. If you're using ingress, you might want to set that label on the ingress service.

Comment: Hello Alev,
Thanks for your response i have one more request to you i am not much aware about AKS so it will be very thankful to you if you told me that from where i can add annotations in service templates or in ingress

Comment: sure! you can use the command:

`kubectl annotate svc service-name service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name=brigadegw`

Comment: Hello Alev
Again thanks for this i have use the below command for annotations  Command is:   kubectl annotate svc abc service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name=xxx.example.com  Where abc is my service and xxx.example.com is my external domain name. Command return message that service abc/ annotated but as i checked through web browser it still show default backend - 404 is their any other option that i have to configure for this